# Are there valid scientific bases for psychologist Taibi Kahler's Process Communication Model?

Tags: pseudoscience

In a corporate training course on team work, I quickly realized that the whole course was based on [Taibi Kahler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taibi_Kahler)'s Process Communication Model. After a quick search, it seems to me that PCM is basically a commercial test used for convenience, that hasn't evolved or been updated since its conception. I don't have access to psychology publications (and wouldn't know how to read them).

Some specific claims that seem dubious to me, made by the teacher, are as follow:

- the basics of our personnnality is fixed by age three.
- NASA astronauts have high IQ (above 160), but very low emotionnal intelligence.

My questions are:

- Is there a valid scientific basis to PCM?
- Has it been updated since it was developped (in the 1980s?)?
- Is there somewhere where I can fact check that very specific claim about astronauts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any article validating  the process com on google scholar. Psychologists don't have access to the underlying design of the test. there is no research about it.

What I found is that the only personality theory that has been validated by thorough research is the big five. The MBTI personality theory is not valid.
i found also that psychologists agree that the personality does not change over time which is contradictory to the hypothesis of the process com which stipulates that the personality is like a floor building and that our personality does change (not the building but where in which floor we stand !).

I found it very disturbing that a new personality theory used by the NASA has not been extensively tested by researchers !

Comment: Do you have references for your further claims on the Big Five of the consensus of psychologists? It seems weird that personality would be static through life.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has been updated. I suggest you read "Seeing People Through" by Dr. Nate Regier (2021) or Dr. Kahler's own book, "The Process Therapy Model" (2008) which described the development of the model from a clinical perspective. Both are available on Amazon. Regarding the NASA information, Dr. Terry McGuire, who was NASA's Lead Psychiatrist for Manned Spaceflight from 1959-1996 wrote a paper on the personalities of NASA astronauts and PCM, which is not publicly available. However, a listing (some with links) of books, articles, doctoral dissertations and other research that has been done on PCM can be found at https://www.atoire.com/copy-of-library. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: A brief summary of the underlying research (and results) would make this answer even better.

Comment: It is helpful, thanks! It doesn't quite answer my question on the scientific validity of PCM, but it does give me some threads to follow.